# Understanding 2D Arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

I'm trying to figure out how to loop through all of the elements of a 2D array. I am given a 2D rectangular array of chars (someChars). I am tasked with writing a looping statement that will calculate and print the number of 'x''s in the rectangle.

```
int x;
for (int r = 0; r < someChars.length; r++)
for (int c = 0; c < someChars[r].length; c++)
if(someChars.charAt(r) = "x"){
  x++;}
if(someChar.charAt(c) = "x"){
  x++;}
System.out.println(x);
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to reference all of the variables within the array, and I don't really understand the significance/where the [bracketed] integers should be in reference to the whole thing.

p.s. I think it's abundantly obvious that this is a homework problem. Even if someone were to hand me the answer, it's worth a single point out of approximately 700 total. I'm much more interested in understanding how it works than mining for an easy answer.

Comment: Part one: A 2D array is an array of arrays, so `someChars` has a length - and each element of `someChars` is, in turn, also an array with a length (hence the bracket for `c`). Part two: Then your code goes off the rails, because `someChars` isn't a `String`, you can't use `String.charAt` you need `someChars[r][c]` which is row `r` column `c` - or a single character. Finally, `chars` use `'` not `"`, and you need two `=` for equality (one is assignment) - so `== 'x'`.

Comment: Thanks very much, this aggregated a lot of the information I was having trouble putting together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're given a 2d array of chars then it will be declared as:

```
char[][] someChars;
```

This means you reference a particular value as (for example) `someChars[1][2]`. To check if that character is an `'x'` then the expression would be: `someChars[r][c] == 'x'`.

Other suggestions:

- give your variables sensible names like `xCount`
- initialise your variables so it's clear what they are `int xCount = 0;`
- put `{` and `}` around the blocks following `for`
- indent

Hopefully that will get you started.